# Some questions on basic number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a number of questions related to proofs based on basic properties in number theory.

While I would post them as separate questions, I feel that they are similar enough in the method that should be used to prove them.

Also, please understand that I am sure these questions are very easy for some, they are not that easy to me and it would be great to have solutions explaining things.

1. Show that the tenth digit of $3^k$ is even for all $k \ge 1$.

I don't know how to even start!

2. Show that $n^5-n$ is divisible by 30 for all $n \gt 0$.

I tried to do this:

$ n^5 - n= n (n^4 -1) = n (n^2 -1) (n^2 +1)= n (n-1) (n+1)(n^2 +1 )$

We can try any base case, and then assuming it to be true for $k$ we get:

$ k^5 - k= k (k-1) (k+1)(k^2 +1 ) = 30x $ ($x$ is an integer).

Now I must prove that this is true as well for $k+1$:

$(k+1)^5-(k+1)= (k+1)((k+1)-1)((k+1)+1)((k+1)^2 +1) = (k+1)(k)(k+2)(k^2 + 2k+2)$

How do I prove this further?

3. Show that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n!$ has exactly $1993$ zeros at the end.

No idea how to solve it.

Comment: In question 1: $3^k$ doesn't even have ten digits for $k<19$, but from what end do you count the digits?

Answer (score 2):

Answering the 1st part, $3^{20}$ is equal to 3,486,784,401 which has an odd tenth digit from either end. So, it is actually false.

Also for the 2nd part, to prove divisibility by 30, it is sufficient to prove divisibility of 2, 3 and 5. We can do this using $n^5-1=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$

Out of $n$, $n-1$ and $n+1$, there has to be at least 1 multiple of 2 and 1 multiple of 3.

If $n$, $n-1$ and $n+1$ are all not multiples of 5, then $n=5k+2$ or $n=5k+3$ for some natural no. $k$. By substituting the values in the equation, $n^2+1$ happens to be a multiple of 5 in both cases.

Comment: Ok, Q1 is incorrect. Maybe it meant tens place digit ($0$ in the case of $3^{20}$)? How would I prove that?

Comment: @Swapnil: One way would be to calculate $3^k (mod 100)$ until you get back to $3$ and then just see that that digit is always even. And that is the case, so that might be what was meant.

Comment: What a simple way to prove divisibility by 30. It was such an easy question and I was struggling with induction proof. Great answer.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks. What a simple technique. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

For question 3:

A number $n$ ends in a $k$ zeroes, if $10^k$ divides $n$. As $n! = n*(n-1)!$, it's clear that the number of zeroes on $n!$ is not decreasing. To show that the requested $n$ exists you then need to show that the number of zeroes doesn't stop growing.

Bonus question: Why isn't there a $n$ so that $n!$ ends in exactly 11 zeroes?

Comment: I don't see any reason why $n!$ can't end with exactly 11 zeroes, apart from the calculator saying so. Can you please explain?

Comment: Because 49! ends in 10 zeroes and 50 adds two (why?)

Comment: Well, because multiplying $49!$ by 5 adds another zero, but since it's multiplied by 50, 2 zeroes get added. But how do you know when (for what value of $n$ in $n!$) you encounter $X$ zeroes to prove this.

Comment: Look at the prime factorisation of $n!$ and think about what it takes to be divisble by $10^k$.

Comment: Could you explain by an example?

Comment: By definition $6!=1*2*3*4*5*6$ if we expand this into a product of primes we get $2*3*2*2*5*2*3$. We can collect the prime factor of $10$ exactly once: $(2*5)*3*2*2*2*3$ this means that $6!$ ends with exactly one zero. Look at this to realise what we miss to get two zeroes, and whether we'll get that when we go to $7!$, $8!$, $9!$, ...

Comment: In expansion of $49!$, there are only nine multiples of $5$ (which can contribute a $5$ to the prime factorization of $49!$). (Basically, the $2$s are not a problem since we have $24$ even numbers) So, then since there are only nine $5$s in the prime factorization of $49!$ which only nine $10$s can be formed leading to divisibility of $49!$ by $10^9$, why does $49!$ end with ten zeroes, instead of nine zeroes?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18867/discussion-between-henrik-and-swapnil).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: These are questions solved via modular arithmetic. For example the second asserts that $n^5=n$ (mod $30$), or $n^4=1$.